# Override Samba directory permissions

Tags: linux, samba, file-permissions

I'm trying to understand the samba rights management, but I think I missed a bit. I have 2 kinds of users: guests and users with a login via LDAP.

Now I try to override all permission settings in Samba via the following share configuration:

```
# directory creation mode
    directory mask = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
    directory security mask = 0777
    force directory security mode = 0777

# user mapping
    force group = users
```

The wanted result (777 for directories) only works with guests:

```
> ls -lda *
drwxr-xr-x 2 sven   users 4096 2012-08-02 09:06 authenticated
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody users 4096 2012-08-02 09:06 guest
```

I've also set **unix extensions = no** but this didn't change the behavior. The parent has set the permissions to **777**. The only thing that currently works, is adding the **sticky bit** to Samba directory permissions - but this won't users let delete there files.

Seems authenticated users are allowed to change permissions even with the above settings - is there a way to completely override this?

Comment: Maybe the individual users' umasks play a role here?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - but I couldn't find a hint on how to configure samba to ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it by using 2777 instead of 0777. Currently I can't explain why that works, but it does. Please note that it sets the **group ID** bit, which means that files below have the group set to the directories group.

Comment: For me, `0777` works for Mac clients but not for Windows clients (good thing it’s a SERVER setting). If I set `security = share`, then `0777` works for Windows clients, but Mac clients cannot connect anymore. It must be a bug in Samba.